# Firefox Extension Execution Priority

Tags: firefox-addon

I couldn't find it anywhere on Mozilla's documentation. Suppose I code an extension that uses addEventListener on keypress. What is the execution priority if a webpage contains a JS code that calls addEventListener on keypress (or keydown) too? Is it guaranteed that my extension receives the event first?

Answer (score 1):

The event first goes through a "capturing" phase, then a "bubbling" phase. If you use the capturing phase (by putting `true` as the last parameter to `addEventListener`) then your listener will get called before the one on the page, if the one on the page uses the bubbling phase. I guess if you don't know which way it works on the page, then you could just attach it to something out of reach of the page (like the `browser` object, or even `gBrowser`) and then you would be sure that yours goes first. See http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow